# Finding the slope of straight line equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I have $y=-\frac{3}{6}x-\frac{5}{16}$

Can I find the slope of this equation by using $y=mx+c$

Such that:

$y=m(-\frac{3}{6}x)-\frac{5}{16}$

$m= \frac{y+\frac{5}{16}} {-1.5x}$

$m= \frac{1+\frac{5}{16}} {-1.5}$

$m= \frac{7} {8}$

Comment: $m$ is already present in the equation as the coefficient of $x$. Why are you bringing it in separately?

Comment: And since nobody has mentioned it ("too obvious" I guess?), don't forget that $-\frac36 = -\frac12$.

Comment: -3/6 was a typo, meant to be -3/2. So the slope is -1.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, the slope of a "linear" equation is the term $m$, where we write the equation in the form $y=mx+b$. As it turns out, because you have given the equation
$$ y=-\frac{3}{6}x-\frac{15}{16}$$
we can see that 
$$ m=-\frac{3}{6},b=-\frac{15}{16}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider the line equation as $$y=mx+c$$ in your example
 $m=-\frac{3}{6}$ and $c=-\frac{5}{16}$ so the slop of line is $-\frac{3}{6}$ that is all.

Answer (score 1):

The slope is: $-\dfrac{3}{6}=-\dfrac{1}{2}$.But in your case , you must find $m = 1$ because you put: $y = m\left( - \dfrac{3}{6}x\right)-\dfrac{5}{16}$

In the general case, the slope of a linear equation: 
$$y = ax+b $$ is $a$.